# union all on views based on table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

i have a database table with a list of sql views

i want to create a new view or stored procedure that based on which views are in that table will return those views unioned
like this

```
SELECT     ALINE1, HOME, EMAIL, EXPIRE, EDATE7, type
    FROM         dbo.campaign_membership_30
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     ALINE1, HOME, EMAIL, EXPIRE, EDATE7, type
    FROM         dbo.campaign_membership_30n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     ALINE1, HOME, EMAIL, EXPIRE, EDATE7, type
    FROM         dbo.campaign_membership_60n
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     ALINE1, HOME, EMAIL, EXPIRE, EDATE7, type
    FROM         dbo.campaign_membership_today
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     ALINE1, BOOKNO, EMAIL, DEPART, DEP7, type
    FROM         dbo.depart_151days
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     ALINE1, BOOKNO, EMAIL, DEPART, DEP7, type
    FROM         dbo.depart_90Days
```

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: And what has stopped you from doing it? And what is the RDBMS? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: my problem is to dynamically create the unions, so lets say i have a web app where i type a view and click add

Comment: i would want it to dynamically add    UNION ALL     SELECT     ALINE1, BOOKNO, EMAIL, DEPART, DEP7, type     FROM addedview

Comment: I see. And what's the RDBMS again?

Comment: @bugz: Do you mean that you have a table where the data in the fields are the names of some tables, views, fields etc? And you want to somehow dynamically build a query from those names?

Comment: @ypercube In a SP. I got that. What I still did not get is the RDBMS. Getting tired of this...

Comment: @bugz: Do you use SQL-Server? If yes, which version?

Comment: and not all of the tables are related, but there all queries in which i basically need the email address to send emails too

Comment: i use sql server 2005, sorry it was hard to word my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of major caveats here.

First, using dynamic SQL is often dangerous. It can open up your database to SQL injection attacks. If you don't understand what these are then you need to do a lot of educating of yourself before I would suggest that you use dynamic SQL.

Second, this kind of a pattern (storing tables and columns in a table from which to generate SQL) is a really bad pattern. There are many problems with it. I can't suggest alternative solutions though without knowing more about your application/problem space.

That said, the following is a simplistic version of how it might work in SQL Server 2005. **This does not include error handling, etc.**

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)  -- NVARCHAR if you use unicode characters in table names

SELECT
    @sql = dbo.Concatenated_Rows('SELECT col1, col2 FROM ' + MT.table_name + ' UNION ALL ')
FROM
    dbo.My_Table MT

-- Remove the extra UNION ALL
SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 1, LEN(@sql) - 11)

EXEC(@sql)
```

The function Concatenated_Rows would have to be written. You could alternatively use a cursor or maybe even FOR XML to create the concatenated string. Here's [a link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) that does a good job explaining many of the possible methods and does a good job of comparing them.

Again, there are probably better solutions out there then going this route, especially if this is more than a one-off task.

Comment: sorry if this is a dumb question but would dbo.Concatenated_Rows or mt.table_name be the name of my table with all the views

Comment: because i get an error at dbo.Concatenated_Rows 

when i do 

SELECT @sql = dbo.Concatenated_Rows('SELECT email FROM ' + dbo.email_campaigns + ' UNION ALL ') FROM dbo.email_campaigns

Comment: Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Procedure testemailcampaign, Line 21
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.Concatenated_Rows", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: Your table with all of the views would be dbo.My_Table. As I said, the function, Concatenated_Rows would have to be written. If you follow the link that I included you can see an example of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for a way to have a table drive which views are part of the query.  In other words, if your table had the following rows:

```
dbo.View1
dbo.View2
dbo.View3
```

Your query would return the union of of those three views; correct?

A caveat: I highly question the underlying relational structures that require you to do this.  A better data model would probably render this unnecessary.  But I'm assuming you don't have the ability to change model, so try this:

Assume the three views listed above are in a field called "ViewName" on a table called "ViewsToReturn."  Construct a query that first unions *all* of the views, then filters it according to the names of the views in ViewsToReturn.  Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT Field1, Field2, 'dbo.View1' AS ViewName FROM dbo.View1
    UNION
    SELECT Field1, Field2, 'dbo.View2' AS ViewName FROM dbo.View2
    UNION
    SELECT Field1, Field2, 'dbo.View3' AS ViewName FROM dbo.View3
    UNION
    SELECT Field1, Field2, 'dbo.View4' AS ViewName FROM dbo.View4) AllRecords
WHERE AllRecords.TableName IN
    SELECT ViewName FROM ViewsToReturn
```

This solution is neither elegant nor performant, but should do the trick if I understand your question correctly.

Good luck!

Comment: hmmm so if i added dbo.view4 to the top table, i wouldnt need to change anything on the bottom one

Comment: ehh this isnt the way i want to do this because i dont want to continue to keep changeing the sql

Comment: Correct.  But if you added dbo.view5, you'd have to add another line to the query.  As I said... not elegant!  Someone might propose a more extensible approach using dynamic queries in a stored proc, but that's not my specialty.